# How to do nested group by using linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, group-by

I am trying to group my result in the following order.

I want **Entries** which belong to **Teams** which belong to **Schools**.
My Entry model is linked to the User by FK.
My Entry model is linked to Team by FK.
Team is linked to User by m2m.
User is linked to School by FK.

My current query looks like this:

```
var y =
                    (from en in _db.Entries
                     where en.User.School_Id == schoolId
                     group en by en.Team_Id into te
                     select new
                     {
                         Team = te.Key,
                         Entries = te
                     }).ToList();
```

This returns perfectly the Teams and beneath the teams, the respective entries.

```
Teams
|
-Team A
--|
  Entries
   |
   -Entry 1
   -Entry 2
```

How can I nest this all within a school grouping? (in the demo I'm just specifying one school Id but in practice there will be a list of school ids to match to.)

```
-Schools
|
-School A
 -|
 -Teams
 -Team A
   |
   -Entries 
     |-Entry 1
     |-Entry 2
```

I'd like to bind this directly to a gridview.
This is working well but with the additional grouping I'm a little unsure how it will effect this mark up too.

```
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
                    <Columns>

                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="School" DataField="School" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Team" DataField="Team" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Entries">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server"
                                    DataSource='<%#Eval("Entries")%>' DataValueField="Name" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

---

**UPDATE:** [image: Here is a diagram of the models]

Comment: Its a bit hard without seeing the whole model. Could you please post all model classes which are required to construct the whole query?

Comment: @VladimirSachek I updated the question to include a class diagram. Is it clear enough?

Comment: have you tried using joins to query all 3 entities?

Comment: @Bayeni I'm not sure I understand what you mean? I'm wanting a collection of entries per each team. And a collection of teams per each school.

Comment: ok I understood, I'll revert back with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will return the collection of entries per team:

```
var ColEntries = _db.Teams.GroupJoin(_db.Entries,     
                                      t => t.Team_ID,   
                                      e => e.Team_ID,      
                                      (t, e) =>       
                                      new { 
                                              Team = t,
                      Entries = e.Select(en => en).ToList()
                                           }).ToList();
```

This will go for each school and get a team and its entries

```
_db.Schools.foreach(s=> 
{
   //Fine a collection say "col" 
  var y = _db.Entries.Where(e=> e.User.School_ID = s.School_ID).GroupBy(e=> e.Team_ID).ToList();

  col.Add(y);
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: It is good to get the entries per team. But I need a higher level where we have teams per school. One school > many teams > each team > many entries.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check the second part and let me know if there are issues.

Comment: @mongoose_za pastebin.com is blocked, I can't open it here at work.

Comment: @Bayerni Here is another link https://www.dropbox.com/s/85xt9hbkid0lkwz/grouped_entries.txt. Seems like my pastebin got removed anyway.